# Did I get the updated C++ FAQ links right?

Tags: c++

Can you check the links in the [C++ FAQ](http://parashift.com/c++-faq/)? I updated *all* of them :-)

Context: In an awesome collaborative effort, Bjarne Stroustrup, Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu, Pearson/Addison-Wesley Publishers and I each contributed great info to create a new [C++ Super-FAQ](http://isocpp.org/faq). A few minutes ago I changed the C++ FAQ (AKA "C++ FAQ Lite" AKA "Parashift FAQ") so each section/FAQ provides a link to the corresponding Super-FAQ section/FAQ.

(Topicality: this is about a resource/tool (C++ FAQ) that is commonly used by programmers.)

Comment: I can't miss this opportunity to thank you for both the original FAQ and your involvement in the super FAQ.

Comment: Well, Marshall I really appreciate that you're attending at SO. That approach to formulate a question in 1st place, than just to pronounce the changes (with a non question, as you tried recently), is a lot better for the format required here.
It could be even simpler, like `Where can I find the updates for the C++ FAQ site`.
(BTW sorry for our 1st warm welcome)
Best regards.

Comment: From a quick click through, it looks like all of the links are indeed linking to the correct isocpp.org equivalents (though unfortunately this question is offtopic for StackOverflow :/). Also, like chris said, thank you so much for your wonderful FAQ! It's been an invaluable resource over the years.

Comment: In addition to what @πάνταῥεῖ said, you might establish a series of FAQ  about less known or obvious aspects of C++11/C++14 here on Stack Overflow: you can ask the question and answer it yourself, for instance.  Thanks again for your effort!